# Node: How to store JSON Array in google datastore

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to store following object in google datastore using nodeJS but its returning 400 "bad request" error

```js
{
      "_id":{
          "$oid":"567e9e80067de880273095e0"
       },
       "name":"Windows 10",
       "desc":"This is a Test",
       "isSelfPaced":true,
       "credit":[
          {
             "_id":"56640d4926b67c201b861cde",
             "username":"Akash",
             "displayName":"Gupta",
             "email":"yesitsakash@gmail.com",
             "role":"Author"
          }
       ],
                  
       "video":{
          "type":0,
          "videoKey":"KHATEmotionalFulls_lowb84c0084-836c-008c-a850-328687e23d02.mp4",
          
       },

       "structure":4,
       "category":"test2",
       "subCategory":"dfdfdf",
       "content":[
          {
             "id":"a053915c-8d10-4aa8-b464-c8a99154c3af",
             "name":"Module 1",
             "type":1,
             "topics":[
                "test1",
                "test2"
             ],
             "children":[
                {
                   "id":"46f18a1a-6653-41cb-be5c-002200170bb9",
                   "name":"Unit 1",
                   "type":2,
                   "subtype":"1",
                   "video":{
                      "type":0,
                      "videoKey":"VID-20150920-WA0017ee56049d-2b08-aeb5-9b9c-b5188b1f7324.mp4",
                      
                   },
                   "note":"<ul><li><b>This is a test<\/b><\/li><\/ul>",
                   "isSelfPaced":true
                },
                {
                   "id":"da4f53a3-7ea2-4fa8-9d48-4d7199a3450c",
                   "name":"quiz 1",
                   "type":2,
                   "subtype":3,
                   "questions":[
                      {
                         "question":"New Question",
                         "options":[
                            {
                               "text":"option 1",
                               "correct":true
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ],
                   "isSelfPaced":true
                }
             ],
             "time":3,
             "isSelfPaced":true,
             "desc":"This is a test"
          }
       ],
       "createdBy":{
          "displayName":"Gupta",
          "id":"56640d4926b67c201b861cde"
       },
       "createdAt":{
          "$date":"2016-01-10T17:51:15.635Z"
       },
       "startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       "endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       "isPublish":true
    };
   datastore.insert('test2','test2',data,function(err,key){
    if(err){
     res.status(500).end();
    }
    else{
     res.send(key);
    }
   });
 });
```

NodeJS code:

```js
var keyObject = dataset.key({
    namespace: namespace,
    path: [collectionName,utility.getGUID()]
  });
 dataset.save({key:keyObject,data:data,method:'insert'},function(err) {
  if(err){
   callback(err,null);
  }
  else{
   callback(null,keyObject.path[1]);
  }
  
 });
```

simpler scenario is wirking but how can store jSON Array in google datastore using nodejs

Comment: I think this issue can be solved by re-reading the documentation of the libraries you're attempting to use, and also if you examine the error output (which you haven't provided)

Comment: @Nick as mentioned in my question also its 400 "bad request" error. Any ways this turns out to be a invalid JSON issue and git fixed now. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the JSON payload was malformed.